# How to prevent spark sql with kafka from adding backslash to JSON string in dataframe

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For some reason when I execute code .wriestream.format(json).option(Path).I have  json and for some reason  the tags have all the double "\". I want to remove all the "\".

```
val selectData = kafkaDF.select(($"value" cast "string"))
val query = selectData
  .writeStream
  .format("json")
  .option(path)
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting the value to a string, which includes quotes and slashes already, and then you are writing as JSON, and so it is double-encoding your JSON.

Try just writing as text

`kafkaDF.select(($"value" cast "string")).writeStream.format("text")`

Or not casting at all

`kafkaDF.select("value").writeStream.format("json")`

And if you are writing to a filesystem such as HDFS or S3, then I would suggest using Kafka Connect rather than writing and maintaining Spark code.

Comment: Welcome. Still Kafka Connect is easier to manage than Spark code, and it's built in to your existing Kafka installation

Comment: how can i use  kafka Connect. It is not documented anywhere how to use Confluent's kafka-connect -hdfs scala API. Any link or code snippet will help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no "Scala API". You just run Kafka Connect as a Server... There is no code that you write. That is my point. Starting point - https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect , or you can download Confluent Platform, which just includes HDFS Connect and https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html