# How to prevent adding backslash to JSON string

Tags: json, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub, delta-live-tables

I would like to read events from eventhub using Databricks, events are in json format but they can have different schema (it's important because i find solutions in which the schema was given to from_json(jsonStr,schema) function, but i cannot use it in my use case). When i use
`.withColumn('Value', col('value').cast(StringType()` in dataframe returns json output with backslashes `"{\"time\": 1432826855000,\"host\":......` .

I found a solution [How to prevent spark sql with kafka from adding backslash to JSON string in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353698/how-to-prevent-spark-sql-with-kafka-from-adding-backslash-to-json-string-in-data) but in Delta Live Tables framework we create streaming tables by returning a dataframe, so i cant use this solution.

Should i use non pyspark functions in etl process such as
[How to remove backslash from decoded JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401943/how-to-remove-backslash-from-decoded-json-string) ?
Will it be efficient during streaming from eventhub to bronze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't worry about that backslashes - it's just a visual representation of your string when you display data and it has `"` character embedded into a string.  Internally, data will be stored without backslashes, like: `{"time": 1432826855000,"host":......`.